# Connecting oracle database using Spark/Scala getting error

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, toad

I'm new to Sacala,I have text file where i'm trying to read and load into dataframe thereafter I'm trying to load into database, while loading into database I'm getting error which is given below on other-hand when same credential I'm using in Toad I'm able connect successfully.Any help will be appreciated

text.txt

```
TYPE,CODE,SQ_CODE,RE_TYPE,VERY_ID,IN_DATE,DATE
"F","000544","2017002","OP","95032015062763298","20150610","20150529"
"F","000544","2017002","LD","95032015062763261","20150611","20150519"
"F","000544","2017002","AK","95037854336743246","20150611","20150429"   

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("IT_DATA").getOrCreate()

Driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.com:1521/DATA00.WORLD



username=xxx
password=xxx

val dbProp = new java.util.Properties
    dbProp.setProperty("driver", Driver)
    dbProp.setProperty("user", username)
    dbProp.setProperty("password", password)

          //Create dataframe boject
            val df = sparkSession.read
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("location", "/xx/xx/xx/xx/test.csv") 
            .option("delimiter", ",")
            .option("dateFormat", "yyyyMMdd")
            .load().cache()

            df.write.mode("append").jdbc(Url, TableTemp, dbProp)
```

df.show

```
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
| TYPE|   CODE|  SQ_CODE| RE_TYPE |            VERY_ID|  IN_DATE|      DATE   |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      OP |  95032015062763298| 20150610|   2015-05-29|
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      LD |  95032015062763261| 20150611|   2015-05-19|
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      AK |  95037854336743246| 20150611|   2015-04-29|
+-----+-------+---------+--+------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```